# Custom Roles for ASP.NET MVC3 Application using Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory

I have some roles in my AD like example role1, role2
I want to create role in application which I can use to authenticate controllers.
Of course I can use something like that:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "role1")]
```

but in case when someone change name of group in AD, then I must change this Roles in all controllers where I used it. So I'm trying to define my own roles in app which I will using in controllers:

```
MyRole = role1
```

Also I can here put more than one role to one in App.
I'm trying to use something like that:

```
string UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName);
if (roles.Contains("role"))
{
    Roles.CreateRole("MyRole");
    Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, "MyRole");
}
```

but methods *CreateRole* and *AddUserToRole* not working with windows authentication.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: here I found good solution. I will use this now. Any better solution? http://www.codecapers.com/post/Using-Custom-Security-Attributes-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx

Comment: You should edit your question, not post additional information as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solution is a good way to centralize your authentication management.  It won't allow you to create new roles, and honestly, that's probably not a good idea anyways.  If you're not in control of them, as you hint at.. whoever is will probably not be happy with you creating roles all over the place nilly willy.

What's more, you would have to grant your web app domain administrator privileges to create the roles, and that's not a good security practice.